Is it possible to serialize a class into XML without requiring the creation of a wrapper class that only holds complex types?
New-ish to C#.
Say I have the following XML (this is just an example.. ignore design choices)
   <body>
       <mywrapper>
           <frontendinfo>
                <version> 2 </version>
                <browser> Chrome </browser>
           </frontendinfo>
           <backendinfo>
                <version> 2 </version>
                <language> C# </language>
           </Backendinfo>
       </mywrapper>
   </body>

In C#, I would assume this has to be done.
    [XmlRoot("body")
    public class Body 
    {
       [XMLElement("mywrapper")]
       public MyWrapper {get; set;}
    }

    public class MyWrapper
    {
       [XMLElement("frontendinfo")]
       public FrontEndInfo {get; set;}

       [XMLElement("backendinfo")]
       public BackEndInfo {get; set;}

...

Is there a way to directly reference the "FrontEndInfo" and "BackEndInfo" classes directly on the "Body" class without needing the "wrapper" element? Something like this:
    [XmlRoot("body")
    public class Body 
    {
       [XMLElement("mywrapper/frontendinfo")]
       public FrontEndInfo {get; set;}

       [XMLElement("mywrapper/backendinfo")]
       public BackEndInfo {get; set;};\
    }


in that, the serializer knows that FrontEndInfo and BackEndInfo should be wrapped in a  element? It would save me much time if I do not need to create empty classes like "wrapper"
Thank you.

I'm not familiar with the specifics of xml serialization in C# so there may be more idiomatic options, but one thing you can consider is a separate data structure designed for serialization (I would use a struct) which Body has the ability to serialize itself to.

XML has been around for quite a while and there are many ways to work with XML, What you've posted is only one of the ways of working with XML The following may be of interest: XDocument and XmlDocument.

Many serialization frameworks allow you to process the object model tree yourself, but it will likely take more time than just creating a few extra classes. You might want to look into tools to generate classes from xml or an xml schema instead.
